# DOSBOX not working on 16.10

Tags: 16.10, dosbox

after upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 I am getting the following error while running DosBox :

```
DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file /home/zetathon/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf
MIXER:Got different values from SDL: freq 44100, blocksize 512
ALSA:Can't subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
DOSBox switched to max cycles, because of the setting: cycles=auto. If    the game runs too fast try a fixed cycles amount in DOSBox's options.
Exit to error: DRC64:Unhandled memory reference
```

Answer (score 11):

Changing the value in the ~/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf from

```
core=auto
```

to

```
core=normal
```

Worked for me and everything seems to run fine now. I've only run a handful of games but so far it seems to be working well.

Comment: it does work but performance takes a huge hit...

Comment: `core=simple` seems more optimal option...

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by recompiling the existing dosbox with a newer version of GCC; ie. the bug got exposed by the newer build process.

It got fixed in Debian in version [0.74-4-3](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=857341). It is present for the first time in [Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dosbox) which means that Zesty and Artful both contain the aberrent package.